# Is there an elegant word for "after we finished the project"?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

I am trying to concisely say, "Trained and coached high value hires after we finished the project."

One attempt: "Trained and coached high value hires postliminary."

Postliminary is the right idea, but it doesn't seem to read well.

"We trained high value hires who took over the project after we finished the job."

That attempt seems clunky and long.

Comment: 'upon project completion' might be your 'when'  - 'high value hires' is a bit of a buzzword term you might be attached to .  "groomed" maybe be another term for "prepared"

Comment: 'readied' , and 'roll out' were other thoughts - brainstorming through all your sentence is more a writing project .. my comment above addresses the more direct question you ask

Answer (score 1):

> Subsequent to project completion...

That's maybe a little grandiloquent.

> Mentored high value hires to ensure project continuity

Mentored has nice connotations, if trained and coached is the customary lingo in your field you can add that back in. Continuity is also a good thing after you leave a project.

> Upon completing the project...

Just another option.

Maybe say what you trained them to do:

> Trained and coached high value hires to prepare them to maintain the completed project